Order Custom field value not showing in WooCommerce with HPOS
I have found a bug in HPOS Woocommerce version.
I have been working on a profit value field for my client to show in Woocommerce > Orders.
The colum "Totaal winst" (english = Total profit) is shown. But it looks like the amount doesn't want to show in the field itself.
For example:

I have seen many simular issues in github and forums. But I don't seem to find the issue.
This is my code
<?php

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if (!class_exists('WooCommerce_Total_Profit')) {

    class WooCommerce_Total_Profit {

        private static $instance = null;

        /**
         * Singleton instance
         */
        public static function get_instance() {
            if (null === self::$instance) {
                self::$instance = new self();
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }

        /**
         * Constructor: Voeg hooks toe
         */
        private function __construct() {
            // Voeg hooks toe voor HPOS compatibiliteit
            add_filter('woocommerce_shop_order_list_table_columns', [$this, 'wtp_add_total_profit_column']);
            add_action('woocommerce_shop_order_list_table_column_content_wtp_total_profit', [$this, 'wtp_total_profit_column_content'], 10, 2);

            // Voeg standaard hooks toe als fallback
            add_filter('manage_shop_order_posts_columns', [$this, 'wtp_add_total_profit_column']);
            add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', [$this, 'wtp_total_profit_column_content_fallback'], 10, 2);

            // Voeg aangepaste CSS toe
            add_action('admin_head', [$this, 'wtp_add_custom_column_css']);
            
            // Gebruik een alternatieve hook voor het verwerken van een bestelling
            add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', [$this, 'wtp_calculate_order_profit'], 20, 1);
        }

        /**
         * Voeg een nieuwe kolom toe aan de bestellijst.
         *
         * @param array $columns Bestaande kolommen.
         * @return array Aangepaste kolommen.
         */
        public function wtp_add_total_profit_column($columns) {
            $new_columns = [];
            foreach ($columns as $key => $column) {
                $new_columns[$key] = $column;
                if ('order_total' === $key) {
                    $new_columns['wtp_total_profit'] = __('Totaal Winst', 'woocommerce-total-profit');
                }
            }
            return $new_columns;
        }

        /**
         * Vul de kolom met winstgegevens (HPOS).
         *
         * @param string $column Kolomnaam.
         * @param WC_Order $order Order object.
         */
        public function wtp_total_profit_column_content($column, $order) {
            if ('wtp_total_profit' === $column) {
                // For testing purposes, display a fixed value
                $profit = 100.00;
                
                echo '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . wc_price($profit) . '</span>';

                // Once the display works, you can replace it with actual logic:
                /*
                $profit = $order->get_meta('_total_profit', true);
                if ('' === $profit || null === $profit) {
                    echo __('Geen winstgegevens', 'woocommerce-total-profit');
                } else {
                    $formatted_profit = wc_price($profit);
                    echo $formatted_profit;
                }
                */
            }
        }

        /**
         * Vul de kolom met winstgegevens (Standaard fallback).
         *
         * @param string $column Kolomnaam.
         * @param int $post_id Order post ID.
         */
        public function wtp_total_profit_column_content_fallback($column, $post_id) {
            if ('wtp_total_profit' === $column) {
                $order = wc_get_order($post_id);
                if (!$order) {
                    echo __('Geen winstgegevens', 'woocommerce-total-profit');
                    return;
                }

                $profit = $order->get_meta('_total_profit', true);
                if ('' === $profit || null === $profit) {
                    echo __('Geen winstgegevens', 'woocommerce-total-profit');
                } else {
                    $formatted_profit = wc_price($profit);
                    echo $formatted_profit;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Voeg aangepaste CSS toe voor de kolom.
         */
        public function wtp_add_custom_column_css() {
            echo '
            <style>
                .column-wtp_total_profit { 
                    width: 150px !important; 
                    display: table-cell !important; 
                    background-color: #ffffe0; /* Lichte gele achtergrond */
                    color: #000; /* Zwarte tekstkleur */
                }
            </style>';
        }

        /**
         * Bereken en sla de totale winst op bij het verwerken van een bestelling.
         *
         * @param int $order_id De bestelling ID.
         */
        public function wtp_calculate_order_profit($order_id) {
            if (!$order_id) {
                return;
            }

            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
            if (!$order) {
                return;
            }

            $total_profit = 0;

            // Loop door alle items in de bestelling
            foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
                $product = $item->get_product();
                if (!$product) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Haal de _gain waarde van het product op
                $gain = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_gain', true);
                $gain = floatval($gain);

                // Bereken de winst voor dit item (gain * hoeveelheid)
                $item_profit = $gain * $item->get_quantity();
                $total_profit += $item_profit;

                // Log winstberekening voor debugging
                error_log("Winst berekend voor item ID {$item_id}: {$item_profit}");
            }

            // Log totale winst voor de bestelling
            error_log("Totale winst berekend voor bestelling ID {$order_id}: {$total_profit}");

            // Sla de totale winst op als order meta via het WC_Order object
            $order->update_meta_data('_total_profit', $total_profit);
            $order->save_meta_data();

            // Log bevestiging van opgeslagen winst
            $saved_profit = $order->get_meta('_total_profit', true);
            error_log("Totale winst opgeslagen voor bestelling ID {$order_id}: {$saved_profit}");
        }

    }

}

// Initialiseer de plugin nadat WooCommerce is geladen
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'initialize_woocommerce_total_profit', 20);

function initialize_woocommerce_total_profit() {
    if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
        WooCommerce_Total_Profit::get_instance();
    } else {
        // WooCommerce is niet actief, log dit eventueel
        error_log('WooCommerce_Total_Profit: WooCommerce is niet actief.');
    }
}

As you can see I have tried to show up the value "€ 100,00" just to show as an example but it doesn't show up.
             /**
             * Vul de kolom met winstgegevens (HPOS).
             *
             * @param string $column Kolomnaam.
             * @param WC_Order $order Order object.
             */
            public function wtp_total_profit_column_content($column, $order) {
                if ('wtp_total_profit' === $column) {
                    // For testing purposes, display a fixed value
                    $profit = 100.00;
                    
                    echo '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . wc_price($profit) . '</span>';
    
                    // Once the display works, you can replace it with actual logic:
                    /*
                    $profit = $order->get_meta('_total_profit', true);
                    if ('' === $profit || null === $profit) {
                        echo __('Geen winstgegevens', 'woocommerce-total-profit');
                    } else {
                        $formatted_profit = wc_price($profit);
                        echo $formatted_profit;
                    }
                    */
                }
            }

Show "€ 100,00" in the "Total profit" field. This way I can add further on the value of the profit by all articles that have been bought.

Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78692868/add-order-total-weight-to-woocommerce-admin-orders-list-hpos-compatible

@snuffy : This fixed the issue! Thank you!
